# String set is cleared when request is called: Swift in-app purchases

Tags: swift

I'm trying to implement in-app purchases in my game, but when I send the set of available products to my products request function, the set is cleared.

This is for a small purchase to disable ads. The button to start the request works and the productIdentifiers in fetchAvailableProducts includes the correct product, but the set is empty in productsRequest.

```
func fetchAvailableProducts(){

        // Put here your IAP Products ID's
        let productIdentifiers = NSSet(objects: NON_CONSUMABLE_PURCHASE_PRODUCT_ID)

        print(productIdentifiers as! Set<String>)

        productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers as! Set<String>)
        productsRequest.delegate = self
        productsRequest.start()    
}


extension IAPHandler: SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver{
    // MARK: - REQUEST IAP PRODUCTS
    func productsRequest (_ request:SKProductsRequest, didReceive response:SKProductsResponse) {

        if (response.products.count > 0) {
            iapProducts = response.products
            for product in iapProducts{
                let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
                numberFormatter.formatterBehavior = .behavior10_4
                numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
                numberFormatter.locale = product.priceLocale
                let price1Str = numberFormatter.string(from: product.price)
                print(product.localizedDescription + "\nfor just \(price1Str!)")
            }
        } else {
            print("products list is empty")
        }
    }
```

The console output is:
["com.me.myapp.noAds"]
products list is empty

I have checked the agreements, turned on in-app purchases in my app, and added the in-app-purchase to app store connect:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you add any products in app store connect? Are you sure the product IDs are correct? It seems like App Store doesn't know about your product.

Comment: Yes, I just added a screenshot from app store connect. It is the correct ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly check whether you have done all of them below.

1. Creating In-App Purchase Products in App Store Connect

   App Store Connect -> Features -> In-App Purchases
2. Project Configuration

   Project -> Select your Target -> Capabilities tab -> Toggle on In-App Purchases
3. Agreement checked in apple developer console.

Comment: Yes I have done each of those steps. I'll add screenshots of each to the question. Still doesn't work

Comment: Nevermind. I had to finish the agreement and it works now. Thank you